# images supposed to show up side by side on yahoo mobile but only left is right size left side is squished

Tags: html, mobile, responsive-design, html-email

images supposed to show up side by side on yahoo mobile but only left is right size left side is squished

```css
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  td.wrap-block,
  .full-width {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="wrap-block" style="color:#999;font-size:22px;line-height:20px;padding:5px 5px 5px 0;text-align:center;letter-spacing:1px;font-family:'Univers Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;" align="center">
    <a href="https://www.rvca.com/"><img src="http://res.news.eu.rvca.com/res/boardri_mkt_prod2/7cbce649dd31be8e80529d2c6ddf340b.png" alt="RVCA Shop Look Product 1" style="margin: 0px; display: block; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; border: none; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"
        border="0"></a>
    <div style="text-align:center;padding:10px 5px 0;"> <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #979797;"><a href="https://www.rvca.com/" style="text-align:center;color:#979797;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;letter-spacing:1px;font-family:'Univers Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height:20px;display:block;"><span style="color: #1e1e1e;">NAME OF PRODUCT 1</span>      <br> $50.00 - 2 Colors</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="wrap-block" style="color:#999;font-size:22px;line-height:20px;padding:5px 0 5px 5px;text-align:center;letter-spacing:1px;font-family:'Univers Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;" align="center">
    <a href="https://www.rvca.com/"><img src="http://res.news.eu.rvca.com/res/boardri_mkt_prod2/d90a511434e579e438ddf1e04b0514a4.png" alt="RVCA Shop Look Product 2" style="margin: 0px; display: block; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; border: none; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: auto;"
        border="0"></a>
    <div style="text-align:center;padding:10px 5px 0;"> <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #979797;"><a href="https://www.rvca.com/" style="text-align:center;color:#979797;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;letter-spacing:1px;font-family:'Univers Condensed', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-height:20px;display:block;"><span style="color: #1e1e1e;">NAME OF PRODUCT 2</span>      <br> $50.00 - 2 Colors</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Not clear with question. can you explain more info or send some pic with your expected output.

Comment: Both your `td` are 100% in mobile. Was your intent to make it 50% so both fit? Also for desktop if you want same width have both `td` at 50%.